# How to alternate showing object in different position at different speed with pygame

Tags: performance, loops, button, pygame, alternate

I'm new using pygame. When I run the code I have a GUI with a ball fixed on the left side of the screen. I also have 10 different buttons that represents different speeds. When I click one of speed button I want to change ball position from left to right and viceversa (without moving the ball, just disappaer and appear in the other position) in a loop until I press the button "STOP" or I change the speed. My two problems are: when the code starts my ball is alternating at high speed instead of the speed is 0 (I can't understand why) and the second problem is that when the ball is moving the script doesn't accept other input button. If a press for a long time the button or if a quickly press it more then 30 times, then it receive the command (it's useful)

Here the code:

```
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (83, 175, 190)
#initial set up
pygame.init()
size = width, height = 1500, 650
background = WHITE
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("nuovo alternato")
#circle = pygame.Surface((200, 300))
screen.fill(WHITE)
#drawing a circle
pygame.draw.circle(screen, (83, 175, 190), (105, 105), 100, 0)
pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 255, 255), (1395, 105), 100, 0)
counter = 0
speed=0
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()
logo = pygame.image.load("C:\\...logodef.png").convert_alpha()
start = pygame.image.load("C:\\...startdef.png").convert_alpha()
stop = pygame.image.load("C:\\...stopdef.png").convert_alpha()
uno = pygame.image.load("C:\\...\\1.png").convert_alpha()
due = pygame.image.load("C:\\...\\2.png").convert_alpha()
tre = pygame.image.load("C:\\...\\3.png").convert_alpha()
quattro = pygame.image.load("C:\\...\\4.png").convert_alpha()
cinque = pygame.image.load("C:\\...\\5.png").convert_alpha()
sei = pygame.image.load("C:\\...\\6.png").convert_alpha()
sette = pygame.image.load("C:\\...\\7.png").convert_alpha()
otto = pygame.image.load("C:\\...\\8.png").convert_alpha()
nove = pygame.image.load("C:\\...\\9.png").convert_alpha()
zero = pygame.image.load("C:\\...\\0.png").convert_alpha()
class Button():
    def __init__(self, x, y, image, scale):
        width = image.get_width()
        height = image.get_height()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (int(width * scale), int(height * scale)))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = (x, y)
        self.clicked = False
    def draw(self):
        action = False
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if self.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1 and self.clicked == False:
                self.clicked = True
                action = True
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 0:
            self.clicked = False               
        screen.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))
        return action
immagine = Button(500, 430, logo, 1)
buttonvel1 = Button(200, 250, uno, 1)
buttonvel2 = Button(350, 250, due, 1)
buttonvel3 = Button(500, 250, tre, 1)
buttonvel4 = Button(650, 250, quattro, 1)
buttonvel5 = Button(800, 250, cinque, 1)
buttonvel6 = Button(950, 250, sei, 1)
buttonvel7 = Button(1100, 250, sette, 1)
buttonvel8 = Button(1250, 250, otto, 1)
buttonvel9 = Button(1400, 250, nove, 1)
buttonvel0 = Button(50, 250, zero, 1)
buttonstart = Button(400, 350, start, 1)
buttonstop = Button(900, 350, stop, 1)
clock=pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
    if counter % 2 == 0:
        fl_color = BLUE
        fl_color2 = WHITE
    else:
        fl_color = WHITE
        fl_color2 = BLUE
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, fl_color, (105, 105), 100, 0)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, fl_color2, (1395, 105), 100, 0)
    pygame.display.flip()
    counter += 1
    clock.tick(speed) 
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame_widgets.update(event)
    screen.fill(background)
    immagine.draw()
    if buttonstart.draw() == True:
        speed = 1
        print("Click su START")
    if buttonstop.draw() == True:
        speed = 100
        print("Click su STOP")
    if buttonvel1.draw() == True:
        speed = 0.2
        print("Click su 1")
    if buttonvel2.draw() == True:
        speed = 0.4
        print("Click su 2")
    if buttonvel3.draw() == True:
        speed = 0.6 
        print("Click su 3")
    if buttonvel4.draw() == True:
        speed = 0.8
        print("Click su 4")
    if buttonvel5.draw() == True:
        speed = 1
        print("Click su 5")
    if buttonvel6.draw() == True:
        speed = 1.2   
        print("Click su 6")
    if buttonvel7.draw() == True:
        speed = 1.4
        print("Click su 7")
    if buttonvel8.draw() == True:
        speed = 1.6
        print("Click su 8")
    if buttonvel9.draw() == True:
        speed = 1.8     
        print("Click su 9") 
    if buttonvel0.draw() == True:
        speed = 0.1   
        print("Click su 0")
```

Comment: Right of the bat, I see a big issue with your code alreay. What you are suppose to pass into `clock.tick()` is fps but you pass your speed variable. Do not use FPS as a way to control speed. FPS as to do with the number of time the main loop will run every seconds, it has to do with performance but certainly not speed of the gameplay.

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain exactly what you want your code to do ? From what I understand, you have a ball and a few buttons that change it's speed, and then idk ? Am I correct and is there more to it ?

Comment: thanks @Anto , yes. You understand. In another gui i'm moving my ball with 'move(speed)' from left to right and viceversa. Now I want to do the same but not showing the ball moving, but just disappear from left and appear to right in a loop. WIth the buttons I would change the speed or stop/start again the ball moving

Comment: So pretty much, you ball will blink from left to right and your buttons will control the speed of that blinking. Is that it ?

Comment: @Anto yes, that's it

Comment: You have two ways you go about that. 1) Don't increment your values like you are doing, just look into creating a timer and teleport you ball by hard setting it's coordinates. 2) You could have a bool global var like `show_ball` and you only draw your ball `if show_ball:` then simply move your ball while it's hidden

Comment: @Anto thank you so much. How I can manage the different speeds? in your first way I supposed I can use different timers, right? In your second hypotesis the problem is just how to set up different speeds

Comment: I'll write an anwser to group everything we said and answer what you just asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve your problem in two ways.

1. Instead of increasing your value progressively like you are doing, create a timer and hard set your ball's position to the right or the left emplacement.
2. You could have a bool global var like `show_ball` and you only draw your ball `if show_ball:`. You can now move your ball while it's hidden.

---

If you choose option one. Define your right and left emplacements :

```py
RIGHT_EMPLACEMENT = (25, 25)
LEFT_EMPLACEMENT = (475, 25)
```

Create a blinking_speed var :

```py
blinking_speed = 50
```

Then create a custom event and timer to go with it (put it to 0 if you don't want the ball to move at first) :

```py
BLINK = pg.USEREVENT
pg.time.set_timer(BLINK, blinking_speed) # Or 0 if you wish
```

Then simply catch your BLINK event :

```py
for evt in pg.event.get():
    if evt.type == BLINK:
        blink()
```

Finally you can manage your logic inside blink :

```py
def blink():
    if ball_pos == right_emplacement:
        ball_pos = left_emplacement
    else:
        ball_pos = right_emplacement
```

Your button can just redefine your timer (it will override the previous timer):

```py
blinking_speed = some_value
pg.time.set_timer(BLINK, blinking_speed)
```

---

If you go for the second option
then just create a ball_speed var :

```py
ball_speed = 50
```

Then your ball can move from `direction` * `ball_speed`
direction is either 1 or -1 depending on if you are going right or left

---

Other points to consider :
your draw function should only be responsible for drawing the button and nothing else.
See : [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)

Store all your buttons inside a list to simply / shorten your code

```py
buttons = []
```

Happy programming